# How visualize graph changes over time

Tags: graph-visualization

Hi I want to visualize infection algorithm on graph, graph code and changes has wrote with Python, but there is no need that Library or visualization tool (VT) contract with my code. it could be possible and more sensible that first code run and write result in file, then VT read the structure of graph and changes in time steps, so end user just can forward and backward time.
Abstract example for interface file:

```
a-b
a-c
b-c
all blue
----
1:a=red
2:b=red,c=red
```

Thanks

EDIT: graph could be visualized on web, windows panel, java applet or something else, it is not important

EDIT 2: i found [igraph](http://igraph.org/) that seem to work with R and Python,it just results in image format so it is not possible to show over time changes.

Comment: This type of question (asking for tool recommendations) is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I've edited!

Answer (score 0):

I found [dynnetwork](http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/dynnetwork) that is Cytoscape 3.0 app, it support importing graph from CSV that is great and visualizing graph changes  over time in term of variety of node and edge attribute size, label, color, ...
that is what i want

EDIT: it has problem with loading graph with about 10000 node! so i must found another solution

Comment: This isn't the place to be promoting 3rd-party tools. These types of questions are off-topic.

Comment: I don't want to promot an open source student project !! i just say it is working approach to save others time, if it is illegal,  i will remove it (no gain for me, so goodbye knowledge sharing !)